# Import/Export table definitions using SQLServer Management Studio

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

How to import/export table definitions from my dev database to production database(recreate the whole database). I have Sql server 2005, Sql Management studio with power shell.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do tables or the entire database.

For a table go in your dev SSMS object explorer: right click the table, click "Script Table As" then "Create To" then "clipboard" or "file".  Paste the clipboard or open the file into your production SSMS query window and press `f5` to run the script.

For a database, go in your dev SSMS object explorer: right click the database, click "Tasks" then "Generate Scripts", then use the wizard to pick all the objects to include (triggers, roles, schemas, stored procedures, tables, etc..) save this to a file and then open the file into your production SSMS query window and press `f5` to run the script.

Comment: Is there any way to automate this so I can run this process from a scheduled task?

Answer (score 0):

You could create the SQL needed to re-create the database by right clicking on the database node in Management Studio's Object Explorer, and selection Script Database As | Create To | ....

Comment: I tried that and it only gives you some database settings in the script, not all the objects.

Comment: @KM: Perhaps you could expand the question to list the issues you are having in a little more detail.